# Display two lines of text beside an image

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/haymanpl/wuhuu6az/6/), the name and title are displayed inline with the image, looks like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSwSr.png) currently.

But I prefer they are displayed like this vertically centered without the list style and on top of each other beside the image so they're both aligned with the image:

- Title
- Name

```css
.people {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.people img,
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="people">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="//0.gravatar.com/avatar/f9879d71855b5ff21e4963273a886bfc?s=120">
  </a>
  <p class="title">Title</p>
  <a class="name" href="#">Name</a>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you want them to look? like the screenshot?

Comment: No, vertically aligned middle beside the image, but on top of each other. Not below the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE

You can achieve what you want by using CSS flexbox, something like this:

```css
body,
p {
  margin: 0
}
.people-wrap {
  width: 33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

img {
  display: block
  /* remove gap*/
}
```

```html
<div class="people-wrap">
  <div class="people">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="//0.gravatar.com/avatar/f9879d71855b5ff21e4963273a886bfc?s=120">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p class="title">Title</p>
    <a class="name" href="#">Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### OLD answer

Just wrap the elements you need side by side making them siblings , and give the same properties as you had in `.people`

---

```css
body,
p {
  margin: 0
}
.people-wrap {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: red solid
}
.people,
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}
img {
  display: block
  /* remove gap*/
}
```

```html
<div class="people-wrap">
  <div class="people">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="//0.gravatar.com/avatar/f9879d71855b5ff21e4963273a886bfc?s=120">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p class="title">Title</p>
    <a class="name" href="#">Name</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's exactly what i need. Not sure if it can be coded better. https://jsfiddle.net/wuhuu6az/12/

Comment: exactly what I have, way much more simplified, have you ran my snippet?

Comment: Yes, better solution. Thanks. I won't forget the points. Q. Why do i need people-wrap?

Comment: It doesn't display them in columns 33% width like this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/38287657/4643292

Comment: I've updated the answer, and answering your question **Q. Why do i need people-wrap?** Exactly for those 33%

Answer (score 0):

According to what you asked, the code below is what you want (I modified your html/css a bit, and [here's your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuhuu6az/12/)). But remember, you have a 33% width set on the `people` class, so when it becomes too small, the list will fall below the image.

html:

```
<div class="people">
  <div class='col mid'>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="//0.gravatar.com/avatar/f9879d71855b5ff21e4963273a886bfc?s=120">     </a>
  </div>

  <div class='image-list'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>Title</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Name</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
.col {
  display: inline-block;
}
.col.mid {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.people {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.image-list {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.image-list ul {
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Seems like a lot more code but provides exactly what i need. Thanks. I'll give you the points when i hit 15!

Comment: the html could've been shorter, but I think writing semantic html is always a good idea even if you dont necessarily need it (so I didnt need to actually have a `ul` tag with child `li` tags, but that makes the list more semantically correct